# Syncing iPhone doesn't complete due to missing folder

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

Since recently my iPhone syncing to iTunes plays up with a dialog box saying

> Attempting to copy to the disk "Macintosh HD" failed. The required folder cannot be found.

[image: Required folder cannot be found]

When I select the "OK" button nothing changes in iTunes with the syncing process being stuck on "step 5 of 5" forever.

[image: Syncing iPhone (Step 5 of 5)]

On the sidebar the iPhone info is just showing the spinning "sync" icon, which also shows in the status bar of the iPhone itself.

[image: iPhone Syncing]

The whole process doesn't complete unless I quit iTunes. I've tried to remember what I might've changed in the lead up the the syncing playing up, and the only thing that comes to mind is the download of a podcast. The downloaded podcast copied over well.

I've also checked that I'm signed in to iTunes, and I have restarted the computer, just in case. None of that has fixed the problem.

Which folder could iTunes refer to here, that it considers missing, or is there anything I could do to resolve this issue?
What is happening at step 5 of the syncing process?